# How To Use The RelatedEntities Collection To Create RelatedEntities

Tags: crm

I'm attempting to follow the logic describe here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309282.aspx for creating associated entities using the RelatedEntities Property.  Problem is, no Associated Entities are getting created.   I'm attempting to perform this action from within a Pre=Operation plugin... Is it not supported within a PreOperation Plugin?  What am I doing wrong if it?

Here is the code:

```
var collection = new EntityCollection();
collection.Entities.AddRange(incentives.Select(e => e.ToSdkEntity()));
target.RelatedEntities.Add(new Relationship(new_LeadProduct.Fields.new_lead_new_leadproduct_LeadId), collection);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code from the MSDN Example:

```cs
//Define the account for which we will add letters                
Account accountToCreate = new Account
{
    Name = "Example Account"
};

//Define the IDs of the related letters we will create
_letterIds = new[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };

//This acts as a container for each letter we create. Note that we haven't
//define the relationship between the letter and account yet.
EntityCollection relatedLettersToCreate = new EntityCollection
{
    EntityName = Letter.EntityLogicalName,
    Entities =
    {
        new Letter{Subject = "Letter 1", ActivityId = _letterIds[0]},
        new Letter{Subject = "Letter 2", ActivityId = _letterIds[1]},
        new Letter{Subject = "Letter 3", ActivityId = _letterIds[2]}
    }
};

//Creates the reference between which relationship between Letter and
//Account we would like to use.
Relationship letterRelationship = new Relationship("Account_Letters");

//Adds the letters to the account under the specified relationship
accountToCreate.RelatedEntities.Add(letterRelationship, relatedLettersToCreate);

//Passes the Account (which contains the letters)
_accountId = _service.Create(accountToCreate);
```

After some additional testing, the Related Entities Collection must be populated before the PreOperation stage.  So registering this to run on PreValidation works as expected.

Comment: Note that unless there is a specific reason why you need to create records in a pre stage it is generally more correct to create related records in a post operation plugin.

Comment: @Zach, define "generally more correct"?  I'm needing to do a sum calculations on the records that are being created, and updating a field on the parent so the parent doesn't have an update directly after the create, it is created with the correct value.

Comment: It sounds like the created records are "children" of the Target record and that conceptually it makes sense that they would be created as part of the primary transaction.  As long as you are careful not to introduce logic that triggers back and forth from the children to parents within the pre methods I don't see any issue with how you are doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Since a pre-create plugin executes before the target entity has been created in the database you will not be able to create related entities referencing the target.  You should execute related entity logic in a post-create plugin.

Edit:
This answer applies if you are trying to create related records associated with the *Target* in a plugin operation.  Your question did not specify otherwise but based on the code in your answer it looks like this is not what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is not what the MSDN article states.

Comment: Can you provide the reference?

Comment: It's in the MSDN article.  I've added it to my answer.